# .Net Core Multiple Complex models binding issue

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-core

I have actions in my controller (.NET CORE MVC App) that takes two or more complex parameters that should be captured when a data is posted from a client. I would like to perform the call with a HTTP.GET or HTTP.POST method (depending on the situation). I have tried different approaches, but only binding with JObject works fine. Others have null values.

I am trying hard to find out what am I doing wrong. Any suggestions?

Here is my Code.

Controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult GetDataPOST([FromBody]DataFilter dataFilter, [FromBody]SeriesFilter seriesFilter)
    {

        return Json(null);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult GetDataPOSTjObject([FromBody]JObject stuff)
    {

        var content = stuff["dataFilter"].ToObject<DataFilter>();
        var content2 = stuff["seriesFilter"].ToObject<SeriesFilter>();

        return Json(null);
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult GetDataGET(DataFilter dataFilter, SeriesFilter seriesFilter)
    {


        return Json(null);
    }
```

Models:

```
public class DataFilter
{
    public string search { get; set; }
}

public class SeriesFilter
{
    public string search { get; set; }
}
```

Angular:

```
    $scope.SubmitTimeSeriesFilter = function (options) {

        options.search = "Search...";

        $http.get("@Url.Action("GetDataGET", "TimeSeries")", { params: { seriesFilter: options, dataFilter: options } }).success(function (rv) {
            options.success(rv);
        });

        $http.post("@Url.Action("GetDataPOST", "TimeSeries")", { seriesFilter: options, dataFilter: options }).success(function (rv) {
            options.success(rv);
        });

        $http.post("@Url.Action("GetDataPOSTjObject", "TimeSeries")", { seriesFilter: options, dataFilter: options }).success(function (rv) {
            options.success(rv);
        });

    };
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this. `[FromBody]` reads the whole datastream and since the Request Stream is a TCP/IP connection, it can only read forward and can't be rewinded (read: It can only be read once).

As such, you can only have a single `[FromBody]` per action. If you want send more than one model, you need to create a ViewModel which can hold both values.

```
public class DataSeriesFilterViewModel
{
    public DataFilter DataFilter { get; set; }
    public SeriesFilter SeriesFilter { get; set; }
}
```

But since both are strings, these seems a waste of space, so you can just do

```
public class DataSeriesFilterViewModel
{
    public string DataFilter { get; set; }
    public string SeriesFilter { get; set; }
}

public IActionResult GetDataPOST([FromBody]DataSeriesFilterViewModel filter)
{
    return Json(filter);
}
```